# how to copy data of return type string to C++?

Tags: c++, string, com

I have a com objects function having a C# return type of string

```
string getData();
```

In my C++ code I have

```
cpi->getData();
```

where cpi is a pointer to an instance of com object.

How do I get this returned data in a C++ variable?

---edit---

I also have another function called `handlepacket(char* data)`.

How do I pass this `cpi->getData` returned string data to this function?

A C++ code piece will be very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The COM string type is `BSTR`. It has non-trivial memory-management rules. Luckily, the `_bstr_t` C++ class wraps `BSTR` and gives you reasonable semantics. So, `_bstr_t foo = cpi->getData();` is the easiest way.

You can pass this string to a `handlepacket(wchar_t* data)`. The COM string type is Unicode text, not 8 bits data. If your `getData` function returns 8 bits data, it should have returned an array of bytes.